# My avocado plant is 14" tall with only a few leaves on top

Tags: houseplants

Help!  My avocado plant is at least 14" tall but only has a few leaves at the top.  It is very healthy, despite the lack of leaves. 
I started this plant with a humungous pit (see pictures).  The avocado was so huge when I bought it, but upon cutting it open, found this ginormous pit with very little edible fruit surrounding it.  So I thought I'd see what happened if I planted the pit., (i.e. try and get something for my money!) It rooted within the normal amount of time and its' stalk grew to twelve inches and had these really beautiful, healthy red and green leaves on the top.  I didn't know what to do to stop the stalk from getting any bigger, or if I was even supposed to, and was wanting more leaves to develop, so I took a tip from a you-tube video and cut the stalk back to 4".  Nothing happened for quite awhile so I replanted it to a larger pot.  Then a new stalk emerged from the side of the first stalk and pretty much took off from there. The new leaves at the top are not nearly as pretty as the first growth from the original stalk, (hardly any red in them, , mostly green), but they are still very healthy-looking. The new stalk does have a few little tiny buds along the sides of it, but they haven't grown any more as the first ones did. (The pictures shown are of the first stalk that I had cut off originally, and just stuck in another plant pot in order to take a picture for prosperity's sake before it died.
 I don't want this plant to get any taller, I just want a lush, leafy plant!  Any suggestions?  [image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Sorry the pictures are out of order, but those are all of the original growth before I cut back the stalk.

Comment: Might want more light so it’s stretching up to try and find the sun

Comment: My avocado plant has passed away after 16 months :(